# AWS Lightsail Linux instance public_dns_name

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns

What's the public_dns_name for my AWS Lightsail instance? I'm running one Debian instance. The static IP is working when connecting via SSH, but I want to know the public_dns_name of the instance.

Comment: Can you elaorate more on your question?

Answer (score 0):

you can go to DNS zones option in light sail and from there you can create the DNS record for domain and get other DNS records values.

On light sail dashboard DNS zones is option.